# Why DllImport doesnt work with "__Internal"?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mono

I have C++ shared library which export method `int MyFunc()` for both Linux and Windows.

From C# I do call the `MyFunc` with following signature.

```
[DllImport(@"__Internal", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "MyFunc")]
static extern unsafe int MyFunc();
// Later I'm using :
MyFunc();
```

This code works fine on windows but inside linux this throw an exception `EntryPointNotFound`.

I have compiled my C++ library with -rdynamic option and I can see MyFunc is exported as D flag with nm but this also didn't help me.

Without any change if I simply change `DllImport(@"__Internal"` to `DllImport(@"mys.so"` then will work fine on linux but then I have to use `DllImport(@"mys.dll"` in windows which this breaks code cross compatible feature.
So I want to avoid this.

I don't see any mistake that why `__Internal` isn't working on Linux.
Note that I'm using mono.

Any idea why this is not working on Linux ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this on both windows and linux:

```
[DllImport ("mys")]
```

The appropriate extension will be added according to the platform (and this works on both .NET and mono).

Comment: Thank you. This has fixed my problem. However do you know what was the problem with it ?

Comment: "__Internal" is to be used only when the symbol is defined in the executable. You seem to have a dynamic library instead, and then you must use the library name.