# "[DllImport("__Internal")]" - what does the "__Internal" mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dllimport

I am working with unity for an iOS game. For unlocking achievement I need to access a "Achievement.mm" file from my c# code:

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void
       GKAchievement(string achievementID, float progress, bool value);
```

I got this code from a forum. But, what does the "__Internal" means ?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643549/why-dllimport-doesnt-work-with-internal

Comment: It is specific to Mono, tells it to look for the function in your own program instead of another DLL.  I think also required to get your app certified by Apple.  Explained pretty well [in the docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

Comment: This is a great question!

Comment: That's certainly a handy link, @HansPassant !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Plugins link their code to C# unity using `[DllImport()]`.
- `__internal` is a keyword used for *static linking* needed by specific platforms, such as **XBox** and **iOS**.
- Other platforms usually use *dynamic linking*, hence this is not needed.

Please for more info refer to: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.

Comment: Updated again :)

Answer (score 6):

Just the minor tip.

If the library being loaded is `__Internal`, then the main program is searched for method symbols. This happens to be the case on iOS platform.

The plugins on iOS cannot load dynamically. Only statically as @RaxelZ explained.

It is different for OSX, Windows, Android ... those platforms may load plugins dynamically.  For iOS, only statically.

Comment: What do you mean by "load statically" and "load dynamically"?