# Why does iOS link "static" to Unity?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, static-linking, dynamic-linking

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void IOSFBInit(string appId, bool frictionlessRequests, string urlSuffix, string unityUserAgentSuffix);
```

First, sorry for my English.
I already know that iOS use `DllImport("__Internal")` for "static link" to C# script(Unity).
But, other platforms(Android, Windows..) are using dynamic linking not static linking.
Why "only" iOS use static linking to link C# script?

Comment: Why you want to know it ? have any issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[DllImport("\_\_Internal")\]" - what does the "\_\_Internal" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584361/dllimport-internal-what-does-the-internal-mean)

Comment: No, just for curiousity. Thanks for comments!

Comment: @MickyD Similar, but I want to know the exact reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a limit on iOS now. Because the library's signature and app's signature must be the same. But Apple had provided a function of dynamiclly load on macOS.

There is a instance in UnityWebRTCPlugin.

- for iOS use libwebrtc.a
- for macOS use libwebrtc.dylib

This is a brief description about statically load and dynamiclly load.