# DllImport __Internal not working despite correct function setup

Tags: c#, c++, gcc, mono, pinvoke

Using embedded Mono, I'm trying to execute a very simple C function from within C#.

This is the function in C++ code (in global scope):

```
extern "C"
{
    static int __attribute__((noinline)) dllImportTest()
    {
        return 66;
    }
}
```

This is the C# code:

```
[DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint="dllImportTest")]
public static extern int dllImportTest();

public void testCFunctions()
{
    int dllImport = dllImportTest();
    System.Console.Write("Got dllImport: " + dllImport + "\n");
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: dllImportTest
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoGlue.ATestClass:dllImportTest ()
  at MonoGlue.ATestClass.testCFunctions () [0x0000a] in <9effaf2265b34fbcb9a10abd58c42ed7>:0
```

I've been looking at examples and similar problems, but I fail to see what is going wrong. To make sure the C function does not get optimized away, I execute it in the C++ code.
I even prevent inlining, as you can see.

However, still no luck. There must still be something I'm missing.

Comment: it seems that the dll itself is not found. Have you ensured that the dll can be found by your application?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.entrypointnotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: "__Internal" means it is not an external DLL, but the environment embedding C# :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643549/why-dllimport-doesnt-work-with-internal

Comment: Nope, no deal. I tried with mys, mys.so, etc. They all lead to a System.DllNotFoundException . __Internal must be the correct thing, but it does not find the function.

Comment: Well, show us the linker's .map file so we can see what the real name of the function looks like.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. In the .map file, it was indeed not present. Another unrelated function was, however. And the only difference was that dllImportTest is a static C function. I removed the static, and voila, it works!

Comment: Though I must say, I honestly don't understand why a static C function would not work. It is not a big deal for me, since I don't need the function to be static - in fact, it was static only as I saw it like that in some example. Still, I can imagine this being a bother to some.

Comment: `static` isn't part of the function. It instructs the compiler to generate a symbol with *internal linkage*. `static` really isn't a property of the function, rather than of it's symbol. The statement *"a static function in the global namespace makes little sense"* from your answer indicates, that you are struggling to understand the semantics of the `static` keyword **in this context**.

Comment: I know very well what static in the global namespace of a given file does. It becomes inaccessible to external compilation units. I had assumed, though, that this does not affect visibility for something loaded by C# at runtime. Obviously a wrong assumption. I stay with my statement, though. I mean, why would you want to do that, "hiding" a function with name X from being accessible externally. In "most situations" that is simply not too helpful or required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the dllImportTest function did not appear in the executable due to it being static. Admittedly, a static function in the global namespace makes little sense in most situations anyway.

So replacing this:

```
extern "C"
{
    static int __attribute__((noinline)) dllImportTest()
    {
        return 66;
    }
}
```

With this:

```
extern "C"
{
    int __attribute__((noinline)) dllImportTest()
    {
        return 66;
    }
}
```

Solves the problem.

The reason is that by making a function in global namespace static, it becomes inaccessible to external compilation units, which makes it inaccessible to C# as well (I had incorrectly assumed that this wouldn't affect the C# access).
Things become a little complicated here, so if you want to inform yourself, go ahead and read about compilation units.

If you do require to access a static function (no matter in which namespace), I recommend the "Internal Call" approach - as seen in the [official mono example](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/#exposing-c-code-to-the-cil-universe). It has many other benefits, as well.